# How to show/hide a select list after the selection in another select list is made?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide, selectlist

I have a select list that looks like this at the moment: 
[image]

Now I want the second select list to only show up when a selection/change has been made to the first select list. And when a selection/change is made to second one I want the third+ fourth select lists to show up. 
[image]

This is the code of the select lists:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="content-a">
        <div class='content-row'>
            <div class="select_1 col-md-12">
                <span>
                    <select class="form-control" name="table_names" id="slctTable"> 
                    </select>
                </span>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">  
    <div class="select_2 col-md-12">
        <span>
            <select class="form-control" name="column_names" id="slctField">
            </select>
        </span>    
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="select_3 col-md-3">
        <span>
            <select class="form-control" name="comparisonOperators" id="slctOperator">  
            </select>
        </span>    
    </div>
    <div class="select_4 col-md-9">
        <span>
            <select class="form-control" name="attribute_names" id="slctAttribute">  
            </select>
        </span>    
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: You should put it in a jsfiddle so people can directly edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always try jQuery Hide/Show element

like so have someting to watch on changes in your

```
$(".slctTable").on('change', function(){
   $('.select_2').show();
})
```

or you can check if the value in the firs selections is undefined or null 
first hide the other elements with (jQuery) or CSS

```
 .select_2 {
    display: none;
}
.select_3 {
   display: none;
}
```

and then IF the first selector is NOT undefined or Null the show THEN show selectors

Answer (score 0):

You can use something from links mentioned below.

[Dependent Dropdown](http://plugins.krajee.com/dependent-dropdown/demo)

[Dropdown List Plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Dynamic-jQuery-Cascading-Dropdown-Lists-Plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.You can do using `JQuery`.
Need to add `id` to second  and third row. now on change of First select show the second select row (`Id="step2"`) and so on ...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery(document).on('change','#slctTable',function() {
    jQuery("#step2").show();
  });
  jQuery(document).on('change','#slctField',function() {
    jQuery("#step3").show();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="row">
    <div id="content-a">
        <div class='content-row'>
            <div class="select_1 col-md-12">
                <span>
                    <select class="form-control" name="table_names" id="slctTable">
     <option>Select First</option> <option>1</option>  
                    </select>
                </span>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="step2" style="display: none;">  
    <div class="select_2 col-md-12">
        <span>
            <select class="form-control" name="column_names" id="slctField">
   <option>Select Second  </option><option>2</option> 
            </select>
        </span>    
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="step3" style="display: none;">
    <div class="select_3 col-md-3">
        <span>
            <select class="form-control" name="comparisonOperators" id="slctOperator">
                <option>3</option> 
            </select>
        </span>    
    </div>
    <div class="select_4 col-md-9">
        <span>
            <select class="form-control" name="attribute_names" id="slctAttribute">  
                <option>4</option> 
            </select>
        </span>    
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what do you mean by show, but if you want your list to be filled after a selection in your first select, use XmlHttp Request.

A little example :

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        //TODO
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "your_request_page.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```